I want to boot Ubuntu from the ISO file (to get to the live session to resize the virtual disk)
My setting for Ubuntu 20.4 VM looks like here.

Every time I boot it started with standard booting to the login screen (i.e. not the live session). Can you please advise on how to boot through the ISO file (given these settings) to enter the live session to be able to resize the Ubuntu virtual disk?

Google ist your friend - 10 Seconds:
https://www.wintips.org/how-to-boot-from-iso-on-virtualbox-efi-machine/
